# JavaFX: Handle ComboBox selection event which is inside the TableView Column

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a javafx `TableView` and I want custom controls inside the columns. Say I want a `TextField` in `column1` and `ComboBox` in `column2` and `DatePicker` in `column3`.

I know that I should create a class that extends `TableCell` and override the `updateItem()` method....

But I read that specifically for this purpose we have default classes like `ComboBoxTableCell`, `TextFieldTableCell` etc in the cell package and it is recommended to use them. So I'm able to achieve this with the below code.

```
loadingStatusTableColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn("Off", "Load All", "Load By Time"));
startTimeTableColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(null));
stopTimeTableColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(null));
```

Now my requirement is when I select some value from the `loadingStatusTableColumn` combobox (Say `"Off"`), I want to disable the next 2 columns `startTimeTableColumn`, `stopTimeTableColumn` and they should be enable when I select any value other than `"Off"` in the `loadingStatusTableColumn` column.

1. How to achieve this with my above code(without creating TableCell subclass).
2. Can i achieve the below line effect through FXML?

   ```
   loadingStatusTableColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn("Off", "Load All", "Load By Time"));
   ```

   ```xml
   <cellFactory><MyCellFactory /></cellValueFactory>
   ```

I know the above works because it is a custom class I have, but can I do the below?

```xml
<cellFactory><ComboBoxTableCell /></cellValueFactory>
```

Thanks in Advance!